# Comparing current string to text file Java

Tags: java, string-comparison

I want to know if there is a way to compare a String to a text file to get the best possible answer. 
Example:
We have a this in text file:

```
BANANA
BANTER
APPLE
BASKET
BASEBALL
```

and the current String is: B.N... (with the dots being the unknown characters). Is there a way to instantly get an array or hashmap with the possible letters (so A, T and E) out of the text file?

What I think I should do:
I have managed to get every line of the text file in a arraylist. I should compare the current String to the possible answers in the arraylist and get every character in that word on the place of the dots and put it in a new arraylist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far

Comment: Sounds like a school project, what is your attempted code so far?

Comment: Is this like a spellchecking algorithm or is it an autocomplete algorithm? Reading up on the Aho-Corasick algorithm might be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Please see the [help]

Comment: @JimW it is an autocomplete algorithm. And thanks I will check it out.

Comment: @Shriram I've not tried to write the code since I am clueless how to do it. I've updated the original post with my theoretical explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use regular expressions. Your current String "B.N..." must be translated into a Pattern, which you will match with the other words present in the text file. You can find a tutorial on regular expressions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html).

Here's a little example:

```
public class RegexPlayground {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("B.N...");
        String word="BANANA";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
        if(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println("Found matching word \""+word+"\"");
        }
        word="BASKET";
        matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
        if(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println("Found matching word \""+word+"\"");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No match on word \""+word+"\"");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Found matching word "BANANA"
>
> No match on word "BASKET"

So the overall logic of the program should be like this:

```
String regex = getRedex(); // This is your B.N...
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
List<String> words=readFromFile(); // The list of words in the text file
for(String word: words){
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
    if(matcher.find()){
        // Match found
        // do what you need to do here
    }else{
        // Same here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Worked perfectly!